# How to use recovery phrase in Bitcoin.com wallet app on Android

Tags: wallet-recovery

Can't remember my master password for my Bitcoin account, and loss access to my funds, after I had to reinstall my Bitcoin app

---

I was able to reinstall my wallets on my Bitcoin application, but can't figure out how to bypass the cloud recovery process and use my 12 word recovery phrases to get access to my funds.  I also have the wallet data file, but can't get pass inputting the master password to get access to the data containing my master password.  Please any assistance in this matter will greatly be appreciated.

---

The app info is Bitcoin.com Wallet, that the precise name, also I see Google Play has the name reflected Bitcoin & Crypto DeFi Wallet.

Answer (score 2):

You commented

> **The app info is Bitcoin.com Wallet, that the precise name, also I see Google Play has the name reflected Bitcoin & Crypto DeFi Wallet.**

You mean this wallet https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcoin.mwallet which claims

> The Bitcoin.com Wallet is the easy-to-use, multichain, **self-custody** crypto wallet that puts you in full control of all your cryptocurrency holdings.

My emphasis.

Self custody implies that you should be able to recover control over your money using the twelve-word recovery phrase in this app or in any that supports the same recovery phrase system (e.g. BIP39) and derivation path.

Their support email is shown as wallet@bitcoin.com.

---

Your question asks

> **can't figure out how to bypass the cloud recovery process and use my 12 word recovery phrases to get access to my funds**

They explain the recovery process in [a video on their website](https://support.bitcoin.com/en/articles/5344011-how-to-recover-import-cryptocurrency-wallets#h_c2b2c14baa) and [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ModZwMAUPuQ)

1. Select "ADD/IMPORT"
2. Tap "IMPORT WALLET"
3. Enter the asset type "Bitcoin (BTC)"
4. Select the wallet type (personal or shared)
5. Enter your twelve word recovery phrase
6. Tap the "IMPORT" button